# Salesforce Industry Cloud (E&U) - Contract Term on Product

Tags: vlocity, energy-and-utilities, industry-cloud, product-design, contract-term

Does Salesofrce Industry Cloud (Energy & Utilities Module) have anything related to Contract Term on Product level? It seems to me that when you sell services such as Electricity and/or Gas, Contract Term should be driven from the Product. So this should be the level where it is defined. But i haven't found anything related to that. Can anyone assist?